# Error while using scp

Tags: bash, scp

I use "scp" command in my shell script. How do I get the error log , if that command is not working.

This is how I am using it `scp file username@servername:/specificdirectory/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encounter an error while running `scp`, try doing `ssh` first to the server, `scp` doesn't have a graceful handling of new keys and `ssh` is more verbose with error reporting by default.

To get a more detailed log of what is happening, try running it with `-v`:

```
scp -v file username@servername:/specificdirectory/
```

You must also remember that path starting with `/` are absolute, not relative to your home directory, as such you may want to try:

```
scp file username@servername:specificdirectory/
```

Comment: I am using scp in a script , can i still use -v option and try to get the detail log in a log file?

Comment: `-v` writes debug information to STDERR. so if you redirect STDERR output to a log file then all debug info will be there.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get debug output with `bash` is to use `set -x`.  Typically, any results will be output to [STDOUT or STDERR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).  How that is captured will depend on how your script is being executed.  As per the [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) manpage:

```
      -x      After  expanding each simple command, for command, case
              command, select command,  or  arithmetic  for  command,
              display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the com-
              mand and its  expanded  arguments  or  associated  word
              list.
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually programs in unix environment writes errors to, well, standard error output.
so you can execute your command like this:

```
scp -v file username@servername:/specificdirectory/ 2> scp_error.log
```